# How to exclude directories while using `copyToLocal`

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

I want to copy files from HDFS. I want folders to be excluded while copying files. I tried `hdfs dfs -copyToLocal` but it also copies directories as I tested.

Is there any way/command to copy files but not directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant of @daemon12's answer that achieves the same thing.

```sh
hadoop fs -ls <HDFS_DIR_PATH> | grep "^-" | \
awk '{print $8'} | hadoop fs -copyToLocal $(xargs) .
```

- `awk '{print $8'}` is used to obtain the actual path column from `ls` output.
- `$(xargs)` is used to concatenate lines of paths into space separated string.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no direct flag for `-copyToLocal` to copy only files. But you can make use of linux `grep` to exclude directories from the data you are copying. Something like this:

`hdfs dfs -ls <HDFS_DIR_PATH> | grep "^-" | awk 'BEGIN{FL=""} {FL=FL" "$8} END{system("hdfs dfs -copyToLocal "FL" .")}'`

where,

- `hdfs dfs -ls <HDFS_DIR_PATH>` is for listing all the files and directories
- `grep "^-"` is for excluding the directories
- `awk 'BEGIN{FL=""} {FL=FL" "$8}` is for creating  string with only file paths
- `END{system("hdfs dfs -copyToLocal "FL" .")}'` is for copying the file path list

Note that, instead of `.` in the last command you can use any local file system path.

Comment: Above script Working like charm. Thank you so much.